# ListPreference: refer item in string-array as defaultValue

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-resources, preferencefragmentcompat

I use PreferenceFragmentCompat to generate setting ui.

Here is my simple setting

```
<PreferenceCategory app:title="@string/language_setting_header">
    <ListPreference
        app:defaultValue="en"
        app:entries="@array/language_entries"
        app:entryValues="@array/language_values"
        app:key="@string/key_lang"
        app:title="@string/language_setting_title"
        app:useSimpleSummaryProvider="true" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Here is my array

```
<resources>
<!-- Language Preference -->
<string-array name="language_entries">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>ภาษาไทย</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="language_values">
    <item>en</item>
    <item>th</item>
</string-array>
```

I want to make thing consistency by

```
app:defaultValue="@array/language_values/en"
```

The Android Studio come with error

```
'/' is not a valid resource name character
```

Is there any idea to make thing consistency?

More info https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat

Comment: Your default value should be a string. What's your ```array``` values?

Comment: @PrinceAli add array values

Comment: Try using app:defaultValue="en".

Comment: Sorry it is "en" but I want some kind of @array/language_values/en to make it consistency

Comment: Making it consistent can be handled by shared prefs.